# Installing cv2 for python3.7

Tags: raspbian, python-3, opencv

I've been trying to get opencv to work on my raspberry pi zero w but no matter what I do it doesn't work. I'm using Raspbian Buster Lite (headless) and each time I fail to get opencv to work on the pi i reinstall the OS. I tried following the instructions on these sites ([a](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/), [b](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/installing-opencv-on-the-raspberry-pi/), [c](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/)) to build and installing it via pip following this [site](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/16/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-raspbian-buster/) which was my last attempt. Now when I try importing cv2 in python3 I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libImath-2_2.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me how to get cv2 to work? because I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.